# Slideshow wont restart

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I am trying to create a slideshow for my website but i have no idea 
how to make the array restart. I tried putting a for loop in the function but the page only shows the last image every time it reloads. here is the code:

```
   var i=0;

    function myfunc(){
           console.log(i); 
           slideShowImage.src = images[i];
           console.log(slideShowImage.src);
           /**
           if (images[i] =="Mir.jpg"){
              link = document.getElementById("slideShowLink");
              link.href="http://stackoverflow.com";   
           }
        */
           i = i+1;
    }
setInterval(myfunc,5000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want `i` to wrap back around to 0 after it hits the last image in `images`. Try replacing `i` with `i % images.length` like so:

```
var i=0;

function myfunc(){
       console.log(i); 
       slideShowImage.src = images[i % images.length];
       console.log(slideShowImage.src);
       /**
       if (images[i] =="Mir.jpg"){
          link = document.getElementById("slideShowLink");
          link.href="http://stackoverflow.com";   
       }
    */
       i = i+1;
}
setInterval(myfunc,5000);
```

Comment: % is the modulo operator. For example `7 % 3` means "give me the remainder of 7 divided by 3". So every time a multiple of 3 exists, it is essentially subtracted from what is outputted. 7 is 3 + 3 + 1, which means two 3's are subtracted and 1 is printed out. For your sake you can think of it as "whenever `i` exceeds the size of my array, subtract the array size from `i`"

Comment: You'd better calculate the modulo before assigning a value to `i`, like this: `i=(++i % images.length)`. If not, the value of `i` would increase on and on until it gets out of range.

Comment: @LittleSanti his interval runs every 5 seconds and the maximum integer in javascript is 9007199254740992. It would take 10 billion years to exceed this value.

Comment: @Macmee Yes, but it is also important to spread good programming practices and make people think in terms of _what is right_, not what is probable. The code you post may serve as a pattern to other users for other problems, in which the out-of-bounds situation _might_ be reachable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a component to your function. I think you need to add to your function:

```
    var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
    : $('#slideshow IMG:first');
```

Here is code that I have used to make my own slideshow:

```
    function slideSwitch() {
        var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

        if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');

        var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
        : $('#slideshow IMG:first');

        $active.addClass('last-active');

        $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
       .addClass('active')
       .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
        $active.removeClass('active last-active');
         });
        }

        $(function() {
        setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
     });
```

The function tells it where to start and that at the end, it needs to go back to the first. This is then incorporated in the setInternal at the end.

Here is the css if you want it:

```
    #slideshow {
        position:relative;
        height:350px;
    }

   #slideshow IMG {
       position:absolute;
       top:0;
       left:0;
       z-index:8;
   }

   #slideshow IMG.active {
      z-index:10;
  }

  #slideshow IMG.last-active {
      z-index:9;
  }
```

And the html:

```
    <div id="slideshow">
      <img src="img/img1.jpg" alt="" class="active" />
      <img src="img/img2.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="img/img3.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
```